# Change or add message to Paypal receipt

Tags: paypal

I have a request to replace the the "Ship To" area of the Paypal receipt that our customers receive to have a message that is something like "your item is available at ticket booth". Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the paypal receipt is a standard template.